# gcc -I doesn't change the include directory

Tags: c++, gcc, header-files

I have a folder called `code/`, under this folder I have a folder called `include/` and the source file called `code.cc`, the `include/` contains the header files `a.h`, `b.h`, and these two header files also exist somewhere else, in order to use the header files in the `include/` folder, I added a flag `-Iinclude` in my `Makefile`, but my code still uses those header files in other places, if I include the header files in the way below, my code uses the header files under `include/`, why doesn't the `-I` flag change the include directory?

```
#include "include/a.h"
#include "include/b.h"
```

**Edit**: Directory:

```
code/code.cc
code/Makefile
code/include/a.h
code/include/b.h
```

Makefile:

```
CFLAGS = -Iinclude/
CFLAGS += -m32 
LDFLAGS = -Llib -llits -lrt -lpthread -Wl,-R,'lib'
code:code.cc
    gcc -o code $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) code.cc
```

gcc --version:

```
gcc (SUSE Linux) 4.3.4 [gcc-4_3-branch revision 152973]
Copyright (C) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: Where is the `Makefile`? Is it under `code`? Are you running `make` from under `code`? It's not clear from your question.

Comment: @lurker Makefile is under `code`.

Comment: Where do the `a.h` and `b.h` files *also* exist? Do you have that folder in the INCLUDE_PATH as well?

Comment: `-I` isn't supposed to _change_ the include directory - it adds an _additional_ include directory.

Comment: @JozefLegény They are in the home directory, `/projec/include/`, I tried `echo $INCLUDE_PATH`, I don't have such a env variable.

Comment: @zmb then how can I force my code to use the header files in a specific directory? I tried `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` but made no sence.

Comment: @user4016367: In order to get an idea of what happens here you should post the relevant part of the directory tree of your source code here, along with the whole configuration of your build process. (e.g.: the makefile). Do also note that many compilers do not use the INCLUDE_PATH (`-I` flag) for `#include` directives using quotes, in that case maybe using angle brackets may be the solution.

Comment: @JozefLegény please have a look at the edit.

Comment: Add `-v` so gcc prints the info about where it searches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this setup:

```
code/code.cc
code/Makefile
code/include/a.h
code/include/b.h
```

And by adding `-Iinclude/` to the compiler flags, your `#include "include/a.h"` would look for `include/a.h` in the `include/` folder first. i.e. the compiler looks for `include/include/a.h` which does not exist, and the compiler looks for the `include/a.h` file elsewhere in the search path.

Your code either have to use `#include "a.h"` , or your `-Iinclude/` would have to be `-I.`  -I. adds the current directory to the search path, such that `#include "include/a.h"` would match the file `./include/a.h` Make sure `-I.` is added before any other search paths that would also match your included files.

Comment: Generally, and for GCC, quoted includes search first relative to the directory of the including file.  So `#include "include/a.h"` from `code/code.cc` should first look for `code/include/a.h`.  Effectively the directory of the current file is prepended to the include path.  I would never suggest using `-I.` as it just causes more problems in the long run.  For example, library headers should call each other using quoted-includes to ensure that they *are* calling each other, and not another similarly named file from the include path.

Answer (score 0):

The order of `-I` directives to `gcc` is important. The `-I` directive that adds  "those header files in other places" must be coming before `-Iinclude` for `/include`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
CFLAGS = -I<full_path_to_project>/code
```

if `include` is placed below this directory, and you include files relative to it as in your include statement

```
#include "include/a.h"
      // ^^^^^^^^^
```

If you specify

```
CFLAGS = -I<full_path_to_project>/code/include
```

You don't need to specify relative include paths

```
#include "a.h"
```

Relative pathes specified with `-I` will start with the working directory used by `make`. If there isn't a relative path part from there, you omit the `-I` option, or specify `-I./`.

Comment: My Makefile is under `code/`, in this case, I my CLFAG should be just `-I` only?

Comment: @user4016367 _"My Makefile is under code/"_ In this case you don't need `-I` option at all.

Comment: @user4016367 You are frequently asking very basic, low quality questions on SO. StackOverflow isn't really the place to learn a programming language or tool, you are supposed to be familiar with the basics already when asking here. So study the documentation manuals first. Also you may want to read [these articles](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) from the help section again. Best regards.